# UIImageView not properly showing image

Tags: swift

I am using storyboards to develop a screen instead of programmatically. I am having trouble with a UIImageView showing an image. These are the constraints[image: image of constraints]
However when I run the app and choose an image this is what happens [image: Ex.] [image: Ex.]

I would like for the images to show as how I set the constraints. Here is my code anyway. Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UITableViewCell!


    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    var imageURL = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK:Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    //MARK:ImageView/CAMERA & PHOTO LIBRARY

    @IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker,animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func photoLibraryTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
     func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                imageView.imageView?.image = selectedImage
                tableView.reloadData()



            }
            dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
        }


}
```

Comment: Well, everything you're doing is wrong. That is not how you make a table view. You do not try to directly set the image view of a cell; you must implement `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, and if you want an image to appear when that method is called, you must put the image into some sort of _data model_ which `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` will consult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do take into consideration matt's comment about how to design a `UITableView`, but to fix this specific problem, use the `UIImageView` property named `contentMode.` Via `contentMode`, you can define how the image view is supposed to display images that don't conform to its exact size.

[Here's an article on how to utilize `contentMode`.](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode/)